# Interview: Determine how many x in y?

Tags: puzzle

Today I had an interview with a gentleman who asked me to determine how many veterinarians are in the city of Atlanta. The interview was for an entry-level development position.

**Assumptions**: 1,000,000 people in Atlanta, 500,000 pets in Atlanta.  The actual data is irrelevant.

Other than that there were no specifics.  He asked me to find this data using only a whiteboard. There was no code required; it was simply a question to determine how well I could "reason" the problem.  He said there was no right or wrong answer, and that I should work from the ground up.

After several answers, one of which was ~1,000 veterinarians in Atlanta, he told me he was going to ask other questions and I got the impression I had missed the point entirely.

I tried to work from the assumption that each vet could maybe see five animals a day, in a total of 24 working days per month.

Using those assumptions, I finally calculated (24 * 5) * 12 = 1,440 pets/year, and with 500,000 pets that would come to 500,000 / 1,440 ~= 348 veterinarians.

What steps could I have taken to approach this problem differently, in case I run into this sort of problems in future interviews?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_problem

Comment: Thanks for that link.  Didn't realize it was that kind of problem. I'll keep that in mind for the future.

Comment: The point is to show the interviewer your thinking processes. The correctness of your answer is largely irrelevant, considering that a correct answer is merely a stroke of luck. How you make educated guesses to fill in the blanks -- and what the blanks are themselves.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with your approach. The average pet sees a veterinarian so many times a year. The average veterinarian sees so many pets per week. Crunch those numbers and you have your answer.

Just guessing off the top of my head, I would say the average pet sees a veterinarian twice each year. So that's 1,000,000 visits. I'd say the average vet works 48 weeks a year, sees about a pet every 40 minutes, and works 30 hours per working week. That's about 2,160 vists per vet.

1,000,000 / 2,160 ~= 462.

My answer is close enough to yours, given that the numbers are all guesses.

Answer (score 0):

The point of the question, I think, is to clearly define each assumption you have to make in order to produce an estimate. Your assumptions can be wildly inaccurate; in practice, they usually aren't too bad.

Interesting aside...there's a fun board game called [Guesstimation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002OQU91S) built entirely around this kind of estimation problem.

Answer (score 0):

How many pets are the types of pets that need to see veterinarians? How many vets see pets instead of large animals?

The point of this question isn't necessarily a Fermi question: It's to see how you handle ambiguous requirements that could significantly affect your answer.